# Optimisation Problem of Umbrella

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have $n$ identical opened umbrellas, as shown in the figure attached, and we want to find out how many umbrellas can be placed in a room at most. Is there any ways to find its optimisation value? I have been thinking about this by doing linear programming, but it seems that it does not give the answer.

I want to know,

1. What are the possible ways to find out its optimisation?
2. Is there an optimisation way for any general shape of the room?[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a packing problem, and what's the exact shape of the umbrella?

Comment: How about taking the umbrella in the photo as reference?

Comment: The problem is already incredibly hard for spheres. I doubt anyone can tell anything meaningful about this umbrella.